# substring with regex for between <tr> tag

Tags: regex, salesforce, apex

I am using  regex for below string.

But always get matcher result as false.

Any suggestion?

I want to substring value between `<tr> and </tr>.`

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('\\<tr>(.*?)\\</tr>');
Matcher m = myPattern.matcher(temp);
  while(m.find())
   {
.. do things
}

<tr><td>111</td><td>111@test.com</td></tr><tr><td>222</td><td>222@test.com</td></tr></table>
```

Even I change to `Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile('<tr>(\\w+)</tr>');`, couldn't get true result.

And also this one still not working `<tr>(.*?)</tr>`. I check with http://regexr.com/, but it seem ok. However, when I run the code, not working.

Comment: Why do you want to use regex? There are so many nice HTML parsers ready to make your life simpler. Lets take http://jsoup.org/ for example. You could use `document.select("tr")` and you are done. Now you just have to use selected information(s).

Comment: hi I am using apex on salesforce platform and the value is coming from  grabbing from external source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("<tr>(.*?)</tr>");`

Runable code: https://ideone.com/sm0WWg

Comment: It wasn't coding issue because the value itself has hidden character which make issue. When it was removed, problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: @kitokid Can we know which value it was? It is kind of interesting since `.` should be able to match anything beside line separators. I thought that only line separators ware `\n` and `\r`. Was is some other character?

Comment: @Pshemo, Hi FYI. the value is etcâ€¦ which I can't see in even in note pad. In Note Pad, I realized that when I backspace the "etc" , I need to make two times to reach the "c" character. Then I notice there is something wrong. In excel, it appear as â€¦. I believe this is encoding issue with the original data.

Answer (score 1):

I don't use environment you are testing but since you have to use regex I see one possible problem: `.` can match any character except line separators so it will not match

```
<tr>
   <td>..</td>
</tr>
```

To make it work you can use `DOTALL` flag, so try

```
Pattern myPattern = Pattern.compile("<tr>(.*?)</tr>",Pattern.DOTALL);
```

Comment: Yeah, that... or the double backslash could also be a bit sus. +1 :)